# WSO2 Message Broker Transaction Rollback

Tags: transactions, jms, wso2, wso2-esb

I have made a simple proxy service which is listening on a queue on Message Broker. I have successfully implemented the JMS Transaction that if service encounters any error the message is successfully rolled-back. By default the number of maximum re deliveries are 10, after that the message is delivered to dead letter channel.

**Problem:**

I want to be able to change following two configurations:

**1)** Maximum number of re-deliveries

**2)** Time Between Each Redelivery Attempt

Where will i do these configurations, in my {ESB_HOME}/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file or in my Message Broker.

**Following is my current configurations of axis2.xml**

```
   <!--Uncomment this and configure as appropriate for JMS transport support with WSO2 MB 2.x.x -->
    <transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
        <parameter name="myTopicConnectionFactory" locked="false">
           <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">true</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement" locked="true">CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</parameter>
           <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">topic</parameter>
        </parameter>

        <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">true</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement" locked="true">CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</parameter>
              <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
           <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
        </parameter>

        <parameter name="default" locked="false">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">true</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement" locked="true">CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</parameter>
             <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
        </parameter>
    </transportReceiver>
```

**Note:**
I am using WSO2 4.8.1 and WSO2 Message Broker 2.2.0.

**What i find:**

I have found the solution to first value that is **Maximum number of re-deliveries**, we can configure this value by editing following tag in {$MB_HOME}/repository/conf/advanced/andes-config.xml file.

```
<maximumNumberOfMessageDeliveryAttempts>10</maximumNumberOfMessageDeliveryAttempts>
```

**Unable to find:**
What i am unable to find is a configuration by which i can change the delay Time between each redelivery attempt. Previously i was using ActiveMQ as the message broker in which we can add following paramter to our {$ESB_HOME}/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file.

```
<parameter name="redeliveryPolicy.redeliveryDelay" locked="true">1200000</parameter>
```

I want the same thing in WSO2 Message Broker but i am unable to find any configuration. I tried the above mentioned parameter but it won't work for WSO2 MB.

Comment: You may need to use message store in this case where you can configure those parameters. 
[1] -http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/12/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-2/

Comment: I am using WSO2 Message Broker(2.2.0). My Question is specific to this Message Broker. I know i have to change configurations but i am not finding the place where i can do that change to adjust above mentioned. Or do you mean to say that in addition to this i have to use a separate message store. But that does not make any sense? Please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it cannot be done like this in case of WSO2 MB. You have to setup a message store and a message processor guarding on that message store. And when you have a message processor it can be configured with interval and max delivery attempts.

- https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Dead+Letter+Channel
- http://charith.wickramaarachchi.org/2012/05/another-message-redelivery-pattern-with.html
- http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/10/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-1
- http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/12/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-2/

*(Alternatively, you can setup the maxAckWaitTime, it means it will wait at least 'maxAckWaitTime' seconds between two redelivery attempts)*